# adding GUI to docker on OSX

Tags: ros, docker, macosx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to attach my macbook-air display to a docker container osrf/ros:lunar and getting this error any ideas?

```
 Sushils-MacBook-Air:~ sushilsundaram$ docker run -it --env=$DISPLAY --name ROS-lunar osrf/ros:lunar-desktop-full rqt
 QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display
```

When i run echo $DISPLAY

```
Sushils-MacBook-Air:~ sushilsundaram$ echo $DISPLAY
/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.1SRZN6cAkV/org.macosforge.xquartz:0
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269335/adding-gui-to-docker-on-osx/) by [sushil.sundaram](https://answers.ros.org/users/31419/sushil.sundaram/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2017-08-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is quite hard to set up unix socket.
You might consider using VNC server in the container instead.
See below:
https://hub.docker.com/r/ct2034/vnc-ros-kinetic-full/

---

Originally posted by [reverofggol](https://answers.ros.org/users/40447/reverofggol/) with karma: 56 on 2019-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2